# Why can't I kill a specific thread/query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, kill

I've got some MySQL (innodb) with some deadlocking, and I'm just looking to kill the transactions and move on.

"SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"
shows the following:

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 74D88AFE, ACTIVE 14 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 4637121, OS thread handle 0x7f51f91be700, query id 979092335 ip-10-118-555-555.ec2.internal 10.118.555.555 csjournal Copying to tmp table
INSERT INTO eznode_count_688
        SELECT
            count( ezcot.main_node_id ) AS count
        FROM
            ezcontentobject_tree ezcot,
            ezcontentobject_tree ezcot_all
        WHERE
            ezcot.path_string like '/1/2/26428/26448/86046/86047/%' and
            ezcot.node_id != 86047 and 
                ezcot.contentobject_id = ezcot_all.contentobject_id
        GROUP BY ezcot_all.main_node_id
        HAVING count( ezcot.main_node_id ) <= 1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 890933 n bits 136 index `PRIMARY` of table `mydatabase`.`ezcontentobject_tree` trx id 
74D88AFE lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 8001501f; asc   P ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000074d86b27; asc   t k';;
 2: len 7; hex 73000c91131ac0; asc s      ;;
 3: len 4; hex 8001cd9d; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 6: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 8: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 9: len 4; hex 8001501f; asc   P ;;
 10: len 4; hex d0f62e3f; asc   .?;;
 11: len 4; hex 8001501e; asc   P ;;
 12: len 30; hex 6672616e636169732f6e756d65726f735f61726368697665732f32303131; asc path/to/2011; (total 32 bytes);
 13: len 29; hex 2f312f322f32363432382f32363434382f38363034362f38363034372f; asc /1/2/26428/26448/86046/86047/;;
 14: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 15: len 30; hex 366538613266356538393432333465383232383963396466613963636437; asc 6e8a2f5e894234e82289c9dfa9ccd7; (total 32 bytes);
 16: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 17: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 74D86B27, ACTIVE 194 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
215 lock struct(s), heap size 31160, 4514 row lock(s), undo log entries 9543
MySQL thread id 4636652, OS thread handle 0x7f51f90fa700, query id 979103970 ip-10-118-555-555.ec2.internal 10.118.555.555 csjournal updating
DELETE FROM ezcontentobject_tree
    WHERE path_string like '/1/2/26428/26448/86046/86047/%'  OR
          path_string = '/1/2/26428/26448/86046/86047/'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 890933 n bits 136 index `PRIMARY` of table `mydatabase`.`ezcontentobject_tree` trx id 74D86B27 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
```

I would have expected to be able to kill the thread or query from mysql, but running kill does not work:

```
mysql> kill 4637121;
ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 4637121
mysql> kill query 979092335;
ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 979092335
```

If I use "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" again, I see the same threads/query ids referenced!  Why are they recognized by SHOW ENGINE, but not by KILL, and how can I terminate the thread?  Mysql's process / KILL documentation has been no help.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is showing you the *last* deadlock. The deadlock has already been resolved and one of the queries was killed. Look further down in the message to see which one was killed.